# apache httpd mod_proxy_hcheck in VirtualHost not work

Tags: apache

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_hcheck.html

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ProxyHCExpr ok234 {%{REQUEST_STATUS} =~ /^[234]/}
ProxyHCExpr ok23 {%{REQUEST_STATUS} =~ /^[23]/}
ProxyHCExpr in_maint {hc('body') !~ /The requested resource is not available/}


<proxy balancer://cluster>
BalancerMember http://192.168.0.1:8181/examples hcmethod=GET hcexpr=ok23 hcinterval=2 hcuri=/status
BalancerMember http://192.168.0.2:8282/examples hcmethod=GET hcexpr=in_maint hcinterval=2 hcuri=/servlet
ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
</proxy>

ProxyPass /examples balancer://cluster
ProxyPassReverse /examples balancer://cluster

</VirtualHost>
```

Put the configuration of module hcheck in the VirtualHost,back-end tomcat not accept heartbeat message?

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same problem and found out that this is a [known bug of mod_proxy_hcheck](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60757). It seems to have been fixed in 2.4.26, even though I can't confirm as I didn't test it yet.
Older Apache releases are still common in popular Linux distributions so I thought it could be helpful to know.